# Index partitioned table to prevent Postgres from doing a sequential scan

Tags: postgresql, index, partitioning, performance, postgresql-11, postgresql-performance

I have a Postgres database with a partitioned table that will contain ~2,000,000,000 entries.

I have defined a partitioned database based on the first letter of the "identifier" - this is split into 37 sub-tables, [0-9, a-z, default (catchall for everything else)].

The database is very simple and straight forward, and is defined below.

```sql
create table entries (
  id                bigserial,
  identifier        text null,
  password          text null,
  additional_fields jsonb
)
  partition by list (lower(left(identifier, 1)));
ALTER DATABASE credentials SET constraint_exclusion=on;

CREATE TABLE entries_0 PARTITION OF entries for values in ('0');
CREATE TABLE entries_1 PARTITION OF entries for values in ('1');
CREATE TABLE entries_2 PARTITION OF entries for values in ('2');
CREATE TABLE entries_3 PARTITION OF entries for values in ('3');
...
CREATE TABLE entries_z PARTITION OF entries for values in ('z');

ALTER TABLE entries_0 ADD CONSTRAINT first_letter  CHECK (lower(left(identifier, 1)) = '0');
ALTER TABLE entries_1 ADD CONSTRAINT first_letter  CHECK (lower(left(identifier, 1)) = '1');
ALTER TABLE entries_2 ADD CONSTRAINT first_letter  CHECK (lower(left(identifier, 1)) = '2');
ALTER TABLE entries_3 ADD CONSTRAINT first_letter  CHECK (lower(left(identifier, 1)) = '3');
...
ALTER TABLE entries_z ADD CONSTRAINT first_letter  CHECK (lower(left(identifier, 1)) = 'z');

CREATE INDEX ident_idx on entries(identifier);
```

However, when I run an `EXPLAIN` it says that is it is still doing a sequential scan.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM entries where identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s' LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..140.92 rows=1 width=104)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..43418531.72 rows=308113 width=104)
        ->  Seq Scan on entries_0  (cost=0.00..23239.38 rows=2 width=68)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on entries_1  (cost=0.00..150187.81 rows=6 width=68)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on entries_2  (cost=0.00..94694.38 rows=4 width=67)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on entries_3  (cost=0.00..81656.71 rows=3 width=67)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)

        ... etc.

        ->  Seq Scan on entries_z  (cost=0.00..579207.95 rows=13 width=69)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on entries_default  (cost=0.00..15582.36 rows=4 width=69)
              Filter: (identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text)
```

What am I doing incorrectly? The intelligent partitioning should be able to redirect the query to just the `entries_s` partition, should it not? And then the `CREATE INDEX ident_idx on entries(identifier);` should make the query go through the index?

After adding the explicit query the new plan looks like this:

```
FROM   entries
WHERE  identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'
AND    lower(left(identifier, 1)) = 's'  -- 1st letter of above identifier
LIMIT  1;
```

Output:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.00..2583053.76 rows=1 width=71)
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..2583053.76 rows=1 width=71)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..2582053.66 rows=1 width=71)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on entries_s  (cost=0.00..2582053.66 rows=1 width=71)
                    Filter: ((identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'::text) AND (lower("left"(identifier, 1)) = 's'::text))
```

It's still doing a sequential scan on `entries_s`. Does declaring the index with `CREATE INDEX ident_idx on entries(identifier);` not propagate it down to all partitions?

Comment: Your WHERE clause needs to include the partition key **exactly**, otherwise the optimizer will not eliminate partitions: `where lower(left(identifier,1)) = 's' and identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s' LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I thought in Postgres 11 it was "smart enough" to do that on it's own? https://pgdash.io/blog/partition-postgres-11.html - also, is that the only inefficiency? Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the partition key explicitly (redundantly!). Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   entries 
WHERE  identifier = 'some_identifier_from_subtable_s'
AND    lower(left(identifier, 1)) = 's'  -- 1st letter of above identifier
LIMIT  1;
```

This should allow Postgres to understand it can prune all other partitions from the query.

Can be derived from `$1` of course:

```
AND    lower(left(identifier, 1)) = lower(left($1, 1))
```

You'll still see a sequential scan on the one partition, unless you create an index like you had in mind:

```
CREATE INDEX ident_idx on entries(identifier);
```

That works in Postgres 11 or later because, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.7)

> When `CREATE INDEX` is invoked on a partitioned table, the default behavior is to recurse to all partitions to ensure they all have matching indexes.

In Postgres 10 or older you have to create indexes per partition.

You may have to run `ANALYZE` on the table after creating the index if you follow up with the  query immediately, before autovacuum had time to kick in.

Comment: That significantly improves the query plan, but I'm still running into performance issues (added an edit to the above question). Thanks!

Comment: @JonLuca: I addressed that, while you were editing ..

Comment: The analyze portion is what I was missing! Thanks for the speedy response!